# What is the difference between a[:,:-1] and a[:,-1]?

Tags: numpy, python-2.x

How to understand the difference between `a[:,:-1]` and `a[:,-1]`?

```py
a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
b = a[:,:-1]
print b
```

The output for this is:

```
[[1]
 [3]
 [5]]
```

And for the following code-

```py
b = a[:,-1]
print b
```

The output is:

```
[2 4 6]
```

Comment: Please do not paste code screenshots _and_ come up with a meaningful question title.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

Let's create another numpy array for understanding.

```
my_array = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
```

This array contains three different arrays. That is, `my_array` is an array of arrays.

`type(my_array)` and `type(my_array[0])` will both return `numpy.ndarray`

When you execute `my_array[:,-1]`, this means goto every element in `my_array` and print the last item in that element. The `:` before `,` means all and `-1` means the last element.

So the output of `my_array[:,-1]` will be

```
array([3, 6, 9])
```

meaning- The last element of each array inside `my_array`.

Now, when you execute `my_array[:,:-1]`, the output is:

```
array([[1, 2],
   [4, 5],
   [7, 8]])
```

Meaning- print all the items in all arrays of `my_array` except the last item.
Here `:` means goto all elements and `:-1` means exclude the last item.